# Swift CollectionView reload data after API call

Tags: swift

I have a collection view with API data but, although I `reloaddata()` in `dispatchQueue.main.async`, I am getting Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on collectionview numberOfItemsInSection().

```
var games : Game?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gamesCollectionView.register(GameCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: GameCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    gamesCollectionView.delegate = self
    gamesCollectionView.dataSource = self
    gamesCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    
    fetchData()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.gamesCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

func fetchData(){
        AF.request("https://api.rawg.io/api/games", method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseJSON { AFdata in
   do {
       let game = try
       JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: AFdata.data!)
       self.games = game
      }
    catch let jsonErr {
      print(jsonErr)
    }
   }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return (games?.results!.count)!
}
```

Comment: As API call is asynchronous, so you need to reload the collectionView once you got the API Response.

Comment: That is actually the question i am asking

Answer (score 1):

```
do{
     let game = try JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: AFdata.data!)
     self.games = game    
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.gamesCollectionView.reloadData()//Reload here
     } 
}catch let jsonErr{
     print(jsonErr)
}
```

one more thing i check your api response it will gives me

> {
> "error": "The key parameter is not provided"
> }

check that response in your code and let me know.

Comment: Well You are right. Also add gamesCollectionView reload() in Main Thread.

Comment: @Kudos No problem. AF dispatches its completion handler to the main thread by default.

Comment: It is working but, when i assign games.results.count in number of sections inside the UICollectionViewDataSource i get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: return (games?.results!.count)!

Comment: check that portion there you get results?

Comment: It is nil at number of sections but it is not at data provided by the api

Comment: can you me the result? so, i can help you.